# Question of etiquette on this forum

Tags: discussion

If there's an established question and answers that almost, but not quite, address the issue you are having, is it okay to add your question to the comments?

If you don't and ask a very similar question, somebody's going to object. On the other hand if you do, there's going to be a repercussion somewhere.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asking questions in the comments may be useful if the answer is simple and straight forward. The main problems are: it could be overlooked, the user who answered ( or asked ) may no longer visit the website, or to answer the question may take more time/room than the comment section provides ( chatting is for chatrooms, not comments ).

If you have a question that is *almost* exactly what you're looking for but the answer doesn't quite fit your scenario, create a new question and explain what the question is, link back to the original question, and explain how your question is different, how it is not the same question, or why the provided answer doesn't work in your usecase.

Many questions get closed for duplicate simply because they don't make clear the distinction between their question and the duplicate.

Comment: That's a great explanation. Indicating the other question/answer as well as why it's not quite the right fit shows (1) you are not a duplicate question and (2) that you've actually done some research on your problem (something a lot of people don't do).